# Replace Multiple Characters in a String (XSLT)

Tags: xslt

I need to be able to replace certain characters so that I can use them as CSS classes.

I have strings like, class(name), class&name, amonst others which are not valid CSS classes (As far as i can tell).

How can I use the replace function to replace multiple chracters,

E.g.

```
translate(className, ' ','') (would replace a space)
```

But is it possible to doo this for multiple characters?

Translate doesnt seem to work with &

Example

XML

```
<title>Mary & the Wolf<title>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(title, ' &','')"/></xsl:attribute>
```

So I want the output to be:

```
MarytheWolf
```

But at the moment I get an error with the & character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`translate()` works character-wise:

```
translate(className, ' &#?!','')  // would remove any character in the string #1
```

or

```
translate(className, ' &#?!','_____')  // would replace any character 
                                       // in the string #1 with '_'
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good idea to replace with a char rather than nothing at all.

Comment: Whats the & code for XSLT? ive tried & in the translate but throws an error?

Comment: `&amp;` is the XML escape sequence for the ampersand. It's not that XSLT or XPath require it, but XML itself does.

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work:

translate(title, ' &amp;():/\','')"

The &amp is causing a problem?

Comment: Unless you post the complete line of code you try it with, I won't be able to tell what's wrong. ;-)

Comment: Edited my post added sample XML and XSLT

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there:

translate('abcd', 'cbda', 'CBDA')

would give 'ABCD'.