# XSLT on funky XML

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I'm trying to get some XML into an easy format for dumping into a DB. This is what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<detail type="Courses Taken" gm_recid="FNBYHVW(,7()E)S" >
          <properties>
            <property name="reference" >
              <property_string>M2</property_string>
            </property>
            <property name="Month YYYY" db_name="TITLE" >
              <property_string></property_string>
            </property>
            <property name="City, State" db_name="LINKACCT" >
              <property_string></property_string>
            </property>
          </properties>
</detail>
```

which I'd prefer looked like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses_taken>
    <gm_recid>FNBYHVW(,7()E)S</gm_recid>
    <reference>M2</reference>
    <date></date>
    <location></location>
</courses_taken>
```

I'm not too familiar with XSL, so I'm at a loss for where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: <courses taken> is not valid xml element. Maybe coursestaken?

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial on XSLT based on a small sample of XML. Far too broad to be covered here.

Comment: I'm asking for a very specific solution. If I can fix this piece, I can fix my whole XML doc.

Comment: @WatermarkStudios No you are not asking something specific. Your .xml is incomplete and your ouput is rather abstract. You cannot expect a concrete solution with an abstract input.

Comment: Better? The XML I'm showing is literally the XML I'm getting. I just used a single instance. The gm_recid is a foreign key in the DB, so I can at least link it to an account record. The output is easily mapped to a C# class using XSD.exe and is much easier to manage than the above. Btw...thank you for the reference info below.

Comment: Seriously?! You vote people down for asking legitimate questions about stuff they don't know about? I can't wait for you to ask an incomplete question about something I know about...lol.

Comment: I found this question not so bad in its present state: +1. The wanted solution is possible and not too challenging if `xsl:element` and the `translate()` function are used appropriately.

Comment: @WatermarkStudios yes better. Although I did not vote you down, but I couldn't decide what to do with your document as it was before your editing.

Comment: Ah...understood. Thanks for the direction though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
 "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
 "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select=
 "'0123456789'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAlphaNum" select=
  "concat($vUpper, $vLower, $vDigits, '_')"/>

 <xsl:template match="detail">
  <xsl:element name=
  "{translate(@type,
              translate(@type, $vAlphaNum, ''),
              '______________________________'
              )}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "@*[not(name()='type')]|*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="detail/@*">
  <xsl:element name=
  "{translate(name(),
              translate(name(), $vAlphaNum, ''),
              '______________________________'
              )}">

   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property[@name='reference']">
  <reference>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </reference>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property[@name='Month YYYY']">
  <date>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </date>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="property[@name='City, State']">
  <location>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </location>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<detail type="Courses Taken" gm_recid="FNBYHVW(,7()E)S" >
          <properties>
            <property name="reference" >
              <property_string>M2</property_string>
            </property>
            <property name="Month YYYY" db_name="TITLE" >
              <property_string></property_string>
            </property>
            <property name="City, State" db_name="LINKACCT" >
              <property_string></property_string>
            </property>
          </properties>
</detail>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Courses_Taken>
   <gm_recid>FNBYHVW(,7()E)S</gm_recid>
   <reference>M2</reference>
   <date/>
   <location/>
</Courses_Taken>
```

**Explanation**: Using a variation of the *double-translate* method first proposed by @Michael Kay:

If we have a string `$s` and a string of only allowable characters `$valid` and we want to get from `$s` another string `$s2` which contains only the valid character of `$s` (in their original order), this can be achieved by evaluating the following XPath expression:

```
translate($s, translate($s, $valid, ''), '')
```

**In this particular case we want not to delete the invalid characters, but to replace each of them with** `"_"`.

**We assume that a candidate name will not exceed the length of 30** and use a fixed-length replacement string (this of course can be made as large as wanted):

```
translate($s, 
          translate($s, $valid, ''), 
         '______________________________')
```

Comment: @FailedDev: Yes, very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template name="replace">
<xsl:param name="ptext"/>
<xsl:param name="ppattern"/>
<xsl:param name="preplacement"/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not(contains($ptext, $ppattern))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$ptext"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ptext, $ppattern)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$preplacement"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="ptext"
        select="substring-after($ptext, $ppattern)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="ppattern" select="$ppattern"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="preplacement" select="$preplacement"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="detail">
    <xsl:variable name="elemName">
      <xsl:call-template name="replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="ppattern" select="' '"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="ptext" select="@type"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="preplacement" select="'_'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
      <gm_recid>
        <xsl:value-of select="@gm_recid"/>
      </gm_recid>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="properties"/>
    </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="properties">
    <xsl:for-each select="property">
        <!--Do something...-->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your properties contain space and/or other invalid element characters so you will probably have to decide what to do with the individually.

Also replace template taken from here :

[Replace Multiple Characters in a String (XSLT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554857/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-xslt)

Comment: This code is incomplete (comments), but more importantly some parts of the code are missing and it isn't a wellformed XML document. Please, correct.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Regarding incompleteness this was intended. Regarding not well formed something was left out from the code block. Also at the time of writing the original post was **way** different than what it is now.

Comment: I see. When I run your transformation the result is only: `<Courses_Taken>
   <gm_recid>FNBYHVW(,7()E)S</gm_recid>
</Courses_Taken>`

Comment: Yes I know. As I said the post was different so I didn't know what to do with the rest of the properties and I left it open ended.